# Cursor not returned from Query

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, firebird, delphi-xe, firebird2.5

I'm using  Delphi XE and FireBird 2.5.

Try use a TSQLStoredProc and give me the error "Cursor not returned from Query" when I put the Active property to TRUE.

An dummy example of storedproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE
RETURNS(
  RDO SMALLINT)
AS
BEGIN
  Rdo = 5; 
  /* Procedure body */
  SUSPEND;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, a query like `SELECT * FROM NEW_PROCEDURE` should work (using [`TSQLQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SqlExpr.TSQLQuery)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are supposed to use the ExecProc method instead of Open / Active. Setting Active to true should only be used if your SQL Statement returns a ResultSet (a set of records), which yours doesn't.

Regards,

Stefaan

Comment: It does, doesn't it? It should return a result set of 1 row with 1 column. The `SUSPEND;` statement makes it selectable.